# HTML Options and Values Intechanging

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to make a simple web application which logs to the console the values that are selected in an HTML drop-down menu. However, whenever I change my options in a different select, it ends up showing a value in the `#player` select. For example, if I chose ***Shot on Cage*** and clicked *save*, the console would show that the value to be `b`. If I am not explaining this thoroughly enough, please let me know, and I will try to re-explain my difficulties.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = document.getElementById("player").selectedIndex;
  console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("option")[a].value);
  var b = document.getElementById("what").selectedIndex;
  console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("option")[b].value);
  var c = document.getElementById("where").selectedIndex;
  console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("option")[c].value);
  var d = document.getElementById("when").selectedIndex;
  console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("option")[d].value);
}
```

```html
<select id="player">
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="n">N</option>
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>
  <option value="m">M</option>
  <option value="j">J</option>
  <option value="ja">Ja</option>

</select>
<select id="what">
  <option value="shoton">Shot on Cage</option>
  <option value="shotoff">Shot off Cage</option>
  <option value="goal">Goal</option>
  <option value="assist">Assist</option>
  <option value="block">Block</option>
  <option value="steal">Steal</option>
  <option value="turnover">Turnover</option>
  <option value="drawn">Ejection Drawn</option>
  <option value="ejected">Ejected</option>
</select>
<select id="where">
  <option value="set">Set</option>
  <option value="navy">Navy</option>
  <option value="leftwing">1/2 side past 5</option>
  <option value="rightwing">4/5 side past 5</option>
  <option value="point">Point/3</option>
  <option value="lefttwo">1/2 side 2 meter</option>
  <option value="righttwo">4/5 side 2 meter</option>
  <option value="1">6 on 5 1</option>
  <option value="2">6 on 5 2</option>
  <option value="3">6 on 5 3</option>
  <option value="4">6 on 5 4</option>
  <option value="5">6 on 5 5</option>
  <option value="6">6 on 5 6</option>
</select>
<select id="when">
  <option value="q1">Quarter 1</option>
  <option value="q2">Quarter 2</option>
  <option value="q3">Quarter 3</option>
  <option value="q4">Quarter 4</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Save </button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This will work for you.**

`.getElementsByTagName("option")` will ruin your result as it will select all the `<option>` tags and it post the result as one.

So try this code it will work.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = document.getElementById("player");
  console.log(a.options[a.selectedIndex].value);
  var b = document.getElementById("what");
  console.log(b.options[b.selectedIndex].value);
  var c = document.getElementById("where");
  console.log(c.options[c.selectedIndex].value);
  var d = document.getElementById("when");
  console.log(d.options[d.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

```html
<select id="player">
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="n">N</option>
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>
  <option value="m">M</option>
  <option value="j">J</option>
  <option value="ja">Ja</option>

</select>
<select id="what">
  <option value="shoton">Shot on Cage</option>
  <option value="shotoff">Shot off Cage</option>
  <option value="goal">Goal</option>
  <option value="assist">Assist</option>
  <option value="block">Block</option>
  <option value="steal">Steal</option>
  <option value="turnover">Turnover</option>
  <option value="drawn">Ejection Drawn</option>
  <option value="ejected">Ejected</option>
</select>
<select id="where">
  <option value="set">Set</option>
  <option value="navy">Navy</option>
  <option value="leftwing">1/2 side past 5</option>
  <option value="rightwing">4/5 side past 5</option>
  <option value="point">Point/3</option>
  <option value="lefttwo">1/2 side 2 meter</option>
  <option value="righttwo">4/5 side 2 meter</option>
  <option value="1">6 on 5 1</option>
  <option value="2">6 on 5 2</option>
  <option value="3">6 on 5 3</option>
  <option value="4">6 on 5 4</option>
  <option value="5">6 on 5 5</option>
  <option value="6">6 on 5 6</option>
</select>
<select id="when">
  <option value="q1">Quarter 1</option>
  <option value="q2">Quarter 2</option>
  <option value="q3">Quarter 3</option>
  <option value="q4">Quarter 4</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Save </button>
```

`options[a.selectedIndex].value` this  simple will get you the value of the selected `option` value in the `select` and in *javascript* `option` in a property of `select` which we can combain with `selectedIndex` property and get you value.

Hope this was helpfull.

Comment: this is the better solution - too bad it lacks any explanation :p (I've suggested OP use your solution rather than mine)

Comment: @JaromandaX Ty. The thing is that I was about to put the explanation and you beat me to the answer so I posted the code first. :)

Comment: yeah, my answer was addressing the fact that you can use `getElementsByTagName` on an element other than `document` - I completely overlooked the `options` property (I haven't done browser javascript for too long :p)

Comment: LOL anyway. we are here to learn new everyday right. So happy to learn and teach :P

Comment: @weBBer Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

you have many options split into 4 selects ... `document.getElementsByTagName` will receive them ALL ... so using the selectedIndex is only valid for the fist `select`

you can use `getElementsByTagName` on any element - so, in this case you would use it on the `select` element

```js
    function myFunction() {
      var a = document.getElementById("player");
      console.log(a.getElementsByTagName("option")[a.selectedIndex].value);
      var b = document.getElementById("what");
      console.log(b.getElementsByTagName("option")[b.selectedIndex].value);
      var c = document.getElementById("where");
      console.log(c.getElementsByTagName("option")[c.selectedIndex].value);
      var d = document.getElementById("when");
      console.log(d.getElementsByTagName("option")[d.selectedIndex].value);
    }
```

```html
<select id="player">
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="n">N</option>
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>
  <option value="m">M</option>
  <option value="j">J</option>
  <option value="ja">Ja</option>

</select>
<select id="what">
  <option value="shoton">Shot on Cage</option>
  <option value="shotoff">Shot off Cage</option>
  <option value="goal">Goal</option>
  <option value="assist">Assist</option>
  <option value="block">Block</option>
  <option value="steal">Steal</option>
  <option value="turnover">Turnover</option>
  <option value="drawn">Ejection Drawn</option>
  <option value="ejected">Ejected</option>
</select>
<select id="where">
  <option value="set">Set</option>
  <option value="navy">Navy</option>
  <option value="leftwing">1/2 side past 5</option>
  <option value="rightwing">4/5 side past 5</option>
  <option value="point">Point/3</option>
  <option value="lefttwo">1/2 side 2 meter</option>
  <option value="righttwo">4/5 side 2 meter</option>
  <option value="1">6 on 5 1</option>
  <option value="2">6 on 5 2</option>
  <option value="3">6 on 5 3</option>
  <option value="4">6 on 5 4</option>
  <option value="5">6 on 5 5</option>
  <option value="6">6 on 5 6</option>
</select>
<select id="when">
  <option value="q1">Quarter 1</option>
  <option value="q2">Quarter 2</option>
  <option value="q3">Quarter 3</option>
  <option value="q4">Quarter 4</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Save </button>
```

That being said, this still isn't the best solution - use @weBBer's code INSTEAD

because a `<select>` element has a property called `options`, which you can use the `selectedIndex` property to get the selected `<option>` - see the better answer for an example